# TCPDF - image displayed only once

Tags: php, image, pdf, tcpdf

I'm trying to generate a multiple page pdf with TCPDF version 6.0.010.
The script you see below worked perfectly when I was using version 5.9.009.

Every page has a logo in it. The pdf generated by TCPDF version 6.0.010 shows only once (on 1st page) this logo. 
When I load different images on these pages, the images are displayed correctly(as long as there are no duplicates).

```
    $pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
    $pdf->setPrintHeader(false);
    $pdf->setPrintFooter(false);
    $pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);
    $pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, 10, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
    $pdf->SetHeaderMargin(PDF_MARGIN_HEADER);
    $pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);
    $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);
    $pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);
    $pdf->SetFont('freesans', '', 18);
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        $pdf->AddPage();
        $html = myHtmlTemplate($item);
        $pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');   
    }

    $file = $pdf->Output('myPDF.file', 'S');
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem my work around is to load the image as a base64 image string and use that instead.

example:

```
$img= "myimage.jpg";

$imgdata = 'data: '.mime_content_type($img).';base64,'. base64_encode(file_get_contents($img));

$html = "<img src=\"$imgdata\"/>";
```

This should help, its not a fix and it is a bit slower, but it works for me.
I Trust this helps.

Comment: same reported here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52662271/tcpdf-header-image-only-displays-on-first-page/56681901#56681901

Comment: I'm using this method and it doesn't work. It only shows an empty white square.

Answer (score -1):

Or get the latest version of TCPDF... I had the same problem and upgraded to 6.0.093 and now it works...