# TCPDF - Header image only displays on first page

Tags: tcpdf

I am using TCPDF to generate a 2 page pdf document.

I have added a header and a footer to the document.  The text part of the header and footer shows up correctly on each page however when I include an image logo in the header it is only showing up on the first page.

```
   public function Header()
{
    $this->Image('/home/xxxxxx/public_html/xxxxxxxx/uploads/logo/logo.png',10,6,0,13);

    $this->SetFont('helvetica','B',20);
    $this->Cell(80);
    $this->Cell(0,0, $project->name . ' - Project Plan',$frame,0,'R');
    $this->Ln(8);
    $this->SetFont('helvetica','',10);
    $this->Cell(0,0, $organisation->name,$frame,0,'R');
    $this->Ln(10);
}
```

Does anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: UPDATE:  This appears to only happen with png images - I have tried with a jpg image and it works correctly.  I guess this is a bug?  Does anyone know a way around this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think is not related to header/footer, but I think TCPDF has bug that broken Image function with same image file loaded multiple times as reported here [TCPDF - image displayed only once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16080295/tcpdf-image-displayed-only-once)

bug also present on actual version tecnickcom/tcpdf:6.2.26

I resolve this problem by loading image outside and pass to the function as string.

```
public function Header()
{
    $this->Image('@'.file_get_contents('/home/xxxxxx/public_html/xxxxxxxx/uploads/logo/logo.png'),10,6,0,13);

    $this->SetFont('helvetica','B',20);
    $this->Cell(80);
    $this->Cell(0,0, $project->name . ' - Project Plan',$frame,0,'R');
    $this->Ln(8);
    $this->SetFont('helvetica','',10);
    $this->Cell(0,0, $organisation->name,$frame,0,'R');
    $this->Ln(10);
}
```

Comment: This does work for me (similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/q/59720761/209139), but the PDF takes a long time to generate. Has this bug actually been filed with TCPDF anywhere, do you know?

Answer (score 3):

As said it is a tcpdf bug. In my case I had two logos in header one png and the other jpg. The problem happened only with the .png. Changing the image type from png to jpg solved the issue.

Comment: This may be related to missing images after usage of `page-break-inside: avoid` or `nobr="true"` as stated in https://github.com/tecnickcom/TCPDF/pull/121. Changing the filetype or removing transparency does indeed help.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using base64 encoded string like this:

```
$image = base64_encode(file_get_contents('path_to_image'));
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
<img src="@<?= $image ?>" />
```