# TCPDF png image cannot be rendered in loop

Tags: php, pdf, tcpdf

everyone. I want to generate a pdf that can take png image from mysql database and print it.
What my problem is that the png image only printed once.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
include_once('TCPDF/tcpdf.php');
include_once('DBConnect.php');

// create new PDF document
$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);

$pdf->SetCreator('PDF_CREATOR');
$pdf->SetAuthor('PDF_AUTHOR');
$pdf->SetTitle('Demonstrating pdf with php');

$pdf->setHeaderData(PDF_HEADER_LOGO, PDF_HEADER_LOGO_WIDTH, PDF_HEADER_TITLE, PDF_HEADER_STRING, array(0, 6, 255), array(0, 64, 128));
$pdf->setFooterData(array(0,64,0), array(0,64,128));

$pdf->setHeaderFont(array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));
$pdf->setFooterFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));

// set default monospaced font
$pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);

$pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, PDF_MARGIN_TOP, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
$pdf->SetHeaderMargin(PDF_MARGIN_HEADER);
$pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);

// set auto page breaks
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);

// set image scale factor
$pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);

// ---------------------------------------------------------

// set default font subsetting mode

$pdf->setFont('dejavusans', '', 14, '', true);

$pdf->AddPage();

$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM employee") or die("database error:". mysqli_error($con));
$counter = 0;
$total = mysqli_num_rows($result);
// while($counter<8){
$html =  "

<style>
table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 80%;
}

td, th {
    border: 1px solid #black;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 10px;
}
img.resize {
  max-height:170px;
  max-width:150px;
}
.center {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 50%;
}
</style>

<h4>
Total no. of employee '$total'
</h4>
<table align='center'>
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Employee Name</th>
    <th>Employee Salary</th>
    <th>Employee Age</th>
    <th>Employee Image</th>
  </tr>

";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
  $image = $row['employee_image'];
  // $image_src = 'images/user.png';
  // imagepng(imagecreatefrompng($image_src),$image);
    $html .= '
  <tr nobr="true">
   <td>'.$row["id"].'</td>
   <td>'.$row["employee_name"].'</td>
   <td>'.$row["employee_salary"].'</td>
   <td>'.$row["employee_image"].'</td>
  <td>'.'<img src="'.$image.'">'.'</td>
  </tr>
 ';
}

$html .= '</table>';
// $counter++;
// }
$pdf->writeHTML($html);

$pdf->Output('test.pdf', 'I');
```

So this is my database 
[i use same image for every entry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7VbLu.png)

This one is the output when I'm using png image
[The image only printed once](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oVIGd.png)

If i'm using JPG format there will be no problem. Just with the PNG file. Why I'm using PNG format because I want to use this on my project where user can upload image to the database in PNG and print out back in PDF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this can help you

[TCPDF - Header image only displays on first page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52662271/tcpdf-header-image-only-displays-on-first-page/56681901#56681901)

try to use different .png images, not the same on every loop, if it´s print OK as you can read in the link, there is a bug in TCPDF with the use of same image

Comment: yeah the TCPDF cannot use same image in a page, when i change it to different picture for every row entry, it works just fine. Thank you